# Needed to press the button twice to show inputted data in the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm fairly new to flutter and having some trouble right now. 
So this is how I wanted my code to work:

When a user presses the add button, an Alert Dialog will be shown and prompt the user for input. Then after pressing submit. The submitted word should immediately appear in the list above.

So the problem I have is that the word doesn't show immediately after I pressed submit, I have to press the add button again then only the text widget will be updated with the new word.

So this is the entire code

```
class _NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  __NextPageState createState() => __NextPageState();
}

class __NextPageState extends State<_NextPage> {
  Future<String> createAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController customController = new TextEditingController();
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Enter you food"),
            content: TextField(controller: customController),
            actions: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                elevation: 5,
                child: Text("Submit"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(customController.text.toString());
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  List<String> foods = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D"
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topRight,
                    end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    colors: [Color(0xff00838f), Color(0xff4dd0e1)]))),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment(1, 0.9),
            child: FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 50,
              ),
              label: Text(""),
              onPressed: () {
                createAlertDialog(context).then((onValue) {
                  foods.add(onValue);
                });

                setState(() {});
              },
            )),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50),
          child: Column(
              children: foods
                  .map((food) => Text(food,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        letterSpacing: 3,
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      )))
                  .toList()),
        ),
      ],
    )));
  }
}
```

[The initial screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSUCl.png)

[I clicked the add button and submit the letter E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbzAD.png)

[The E should appear below D, but nothing changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSUCl.png)

[After I pressed the add button again, the E was shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RaRC.png)

Comment: Additional notes: Those alphabets were stored inside a list. So when I add a new alphabet, it is stored inside the list named foods. Then those alphabets will turn into a text widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this:

```
  onPressed: () {
                    createAlertDialog(context).then((onValue) {
                      foods.add(onValue);
                    });

                    setState(() {});
                  },
```

To this:

```
 onPressed: () async {
               var onValue = await createAlertDialog(context);
                foods.add(onValue);
                setState(() {});
              },
```

So you wait for the dialog to return, to update the data on the screen with a setState.